# cannot install/remove packages

Tags: software-installation

I am a novice in world of Ubuntu.

I tried to install first `codeblocks`and then `build-essentials`. However, because the 2nd installation stopped due to a failure in my internet connection, I closed the terminal.
Thereafter, I am not able to install/remove any package.

```
it@it:~$ sudo apt-get install codeblocks

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
codeblocks is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 232 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/cdrom/casper/initrd.gz.new’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

it@it:~$
```

My system have an Intel i7 processor with 4 GB RAM. I am using xubuntu (64-bit-amd)(13.10)(Saucy Salamander) from a bootable USB created using YUMI multiboot installer.

Comment: Try a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Clue: The script is trying to create a file `/cdrom/casper/initrd.gz.new`. It seems to think you are running a Live (uninstalled) system. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a package manager to remove the package, and if you wamt to remove the whole software, maby you can remove it from software center!

Comment: initramfs-tools is used every time the kernel updates.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `codeblocks` installation is OK. However, there is another package that `apt` is trying to configure (the `initramfs-tools`) that requires an update to the initialization at `/cdrom/casper/initrd.gz.new`. These folders and files does not exists and the installation produces an error.

Note that, if you are running a LiveCD, the installer will get an error when it tries to modify initialization files such as `/cdrom/casper/initrd.gz.new`.

---

You may try (1) to remove and reinstall the package which installation has not finished, by running commands such as `sudo apt-get remove <package>`, (2) to use tools such as `aptitude` that suggest solutions to problems with the installed packages, or (3), if you are running a LiveCD, to install the Ubuntu in a non-read only disk/filesystem.